# Outlook 2013 wont display bullet points correctly

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have edited this awesome template to be used for an email marketing campaign. It looks fresh and clean, and seems to be able to serve us well. In Gmail it looks good, it has slight oddities that I cant fix because I think it deals with how gmail reads the code. But its super usable.

But if someone uses outlook to read our email, the message is all messed up. the bullet points are all messed up and not formatted. Here is some code:

> 

```
                  <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#68696a">

                      <ul align="left">

                          <li align= "left" style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:15px"><strong>Exterior Photos</strong></li>

                     <li align= "left" style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:15px"><strong>360 Video</strong></li>

                           <li align= "left" style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:15px"><strong>Social Media </strong></li>

                          <li align= "left" style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:15px"><strong>Fast Results</strong></li>

                          <br>
                          <br>
                     </ul><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:16px"><strong><a href="http://www.dronetrac.net/contact/" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">Find Out More!</a></strong></font>

                </tr>
                <tr>
```

Are there any tips when working with outlook?

THe bullet point looks like this in outlook

```
-blah 
   -blah 
-blah 
-bah
```

google looks like:

```
> -blah
> -blah 
> -blah 
> -blah
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of messages. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Yeah I just coded it so it look good on a browser then print screened an image. Works flawless for me and it was simple. Loads quickly and does the same job. But thanks!